# ngFor inside ngFor causing error

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I have a firebase json object which consists of sections. Inside the sections is also section threads. I'm trying to iterate the sections, and then the threads. Problem is I'm getting this error

**InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'**

when I add the second *ngFor for the threads

This is my HTML

```
<div *ngFor="let section of forumSections | async">
  <div>Header title: {{section.sectionTitle}}</div>

<div *ngFor="let thread of section.sectionThreads | async">
  <div>Thread title: {{thread.title}}</div>
</div>
```

And my JSON object from my firebase database

```
 "forum" : {
"sections" : {
  "Y6ML8AA9V5RB2sKFmKndnHFqRw23" : {
    "sectionThreads" : {
      "-zqehRPSbalaburpm2dW" : {
        "description" : "Sup ladies",
        "title" : "elo mm9"
      },
      "-zqehRPSbalajYGfm2dW" : {
        "description" : "Sup boi",
        "title" : "elo m8"
      }
    },
    "sectionTitle" : "Official"
  }
}
```

}

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Update:

forum.ts

```
    import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPage} from 'ionic-angular';
import {FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2";
import {ForumServiceProvider} from "../../providers/forum-service/forum-service";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-forum',
  templateUrl: 'forum.html',
})

export class ForumPage implements OnInit {

  forumSections: FirebaseListObservable<any>;

  constructor(public forumService: ForumServiceProvider) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadForumData();
  }

  loadForumData() {
    this.forumSections = this.forumService.getInitialSections();
  }

}
```

Forum Service

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable} from "angularfire2";

@Injectable()
export class ForumServiceProvider {

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
  }

  /**
   * Get the forums front facing sections
   * @returns {FirebaseListObservable<any>}
   */
  getInitialSections(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.list('/forum/sections');
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Async pipe needs an Observable, make sure your response is Observable, since you are using firebase, it should be FirebaseListObservable.

in your case, I think if you remove the `| async` in your second ngFor it will fix your issue since it's an array.

Comment: It is of FirebaseListObservable. And I have tried removing the async but then it throws this error "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: from your json, it looks like an object instead of an array, did you do db.list('/forumSections');

Comment: @ZhangBruce correct. `  getInitialSections(): FirebaseListObservable<any> {
    return this.af.database.list('/forum/sections/');
  }`

Comment: @ZhangBruce
forumSections: FirebaseListObservable<any>; 
 
  constructor(public forumService: ForumServiceProvider) { 
  } 
 
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.loadForumData(); 
  } 
 
  loadForumData() { 
    this.forumSections = this.forumService.getInitialSections();

Comment: u need to share your data service, the one which used to fetch data from firebase to check things better, btw did you used rxjs map operator?

Comment: @EmadDehnavi updated post with service. I did not use map

Answer (score 0):

from your comment, it looks like your first ngfor should work, second one wont work because it's not an observable anymore, nor an array . 
so you need to convert second one into an array, **also remove the asyc pipe in second one**.

```html
this.af.database.list('/forum/sections/')
.map(sections=>sections
              .map(section=>Object.keys(section.sectionThreads)
                            .map(key=>section.sectionThreads[key])))
```

I haven't tested it, and it's not typescript, you might need to do some conversion